# How to Insert values on Multiple Table on my data base

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert values into multiple table. Please correct my code because it just double the inserted value on table_attendace

```
if(isset($_POST['text']))
    {

        $text =$_POST['text'];


        // insert query 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table_attendance(NAME,TIMEIN) VALUES('$text',NOW())";
        $query =mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        
        if($query==1) 
        {
            $ins="INSERT INTO table_attendancebackup(NAME,TIMEIN) VALUES('$text',NOW())";
            $quey=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                if ($quey==1) {
                    $_SESSION['success'] = 'Action Done';
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['error'] = $conn->error;
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second query, you reused the first query `$sql` again, instead of using `$ins`.
It should be

```
$quey=mysqli_query($conn,$ins) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can write two queries in single variable with semicolon then you can save the same data in both table.

And
`$quey=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` -> in this line you placed the `$ins` variable wrongly instead of `$ins`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_attendance(NAME,TIMEIN) VALUES('$text',NOW()); INSERT INTO table_ttendancebackup(NAME,TIMEIN) VALUES('$text',NOW())";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```